# Using javascript in Asp.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a problem that I want to call the javascript code, when selection of gridview is changing. But, I can not start my javascript. How can I do that?

//Html side

```
<input ID="addressinput" type="text"  runat="server" style="display:none;"/>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none;" OnClientClick="return myfunction();" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

//Javascript

```
function myfunction() {
    FindLocaiton();
}
```

//C#

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addressinput.Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
     Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: When you change the selected index in your GridView a postback occurs, right? so you want the JavaScript code to run after the postback?

Comment: Yeah exactly. I tried it but I could not write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per following code java script function myfunction() will execute first then the server side button click event.... so u need to add following code in button click event to execute javascript code after server side code..

### ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msg", "myfunction();")

Following is the code that i have tested and its working.

ASPX Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {

        alert('In JavaScript Code after server side code execution');
    }
</script>

   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

C# Code :-

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("In Button Click event");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msg", "<script language=javascript>myfunction();</script>");
    }
```

Comment: and do n't specify OnClientClick="return myfunction();" otherwise onclientclick will execute prior to sever side click event...

Comment: It did not work. I can click my button but I think it did not affect the javascript code.

Comment: I have modified answer and following code is tested and its working...please let me know if u need any other help...

Answer (score 1):

Place a literal with runat server and  fill this literal with the javascript serverside within a stringbuilder